# Need advice for C# LINQ List aggregation expression

Tags: c#, list, linq, aggregation

Let´s say I have this List of type Prices:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 57571,
        "Price": 1745.0,
        "DateAdded": "2018-12-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 67537,
        "Price": 1695.0,
        "DateAdded": "2018-09-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 80042,
        "Price": 1645.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-03-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 155866,
        "Price": 1545.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-04-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 163643,
        "Price": 1545.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-04-26T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 171379,
        "Price": 1545.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-04-27T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 178990,
        "Price": 1545.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-04-28T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

I need to remove all items with the same price, but only if the item is a sibling of the list element. Is there to achieve this by using LINQ?

My expected output would be

```
[
    {
        "Id": 57571,
        "Price": 1745.0,
        "DateAdded": "2018-12-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 67537,
        "Price": 1695.0,
        "DateAdded": "2018-09-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 80042,
        "Price": 1645.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-03-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Id": 155866,
        "Price": 1545.0,
        "DateAdded": "2019-04-24T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

I have absolutely no clue how I can achieve this. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: _"but only if the item is a sibling of the list element"_ - so a list of `1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1` would become `1, 2, 3, 2, 1`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes excactly :)

Comment: By sibling you mean 'adjacent to'?

Comment: @mjwills Yes :)

Comment: Do you think you could provide the source data and the expected outcome as valid c# code?

Comment: MoreLINQ's `Segment` is likely what you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_MzMtiudQA

Comment: @CameronMacFarland This isn't a `DistinctBy` operation. The operation might be called `ChunkBy` or `GroupAdjacentBy`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what is meant by sibling - immediately adjacent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [`ChunkBy` extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-results-by-contiguous-keys) method found in Microsoft's C# documentation, you can

```
myData.ChunkBy(x => x.Price).Select(g => g.First())
```

...or by using [MoreLinq's `GroupAdjacent`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.9/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent__2.htm) you can

```
myData.GroupAdjacent(x => x.Price).Select(g => g.First())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do so using an iterator:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1 };

        var output = GetUniqueAdjacent(input);

        foreach (var o in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetUniqueAdjacent(IEnumerable<int> input)
    {
        bool first = true;
        int previous = -1;
        foreach (var i in input)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                previous = i;
                yield return i;
                first = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (i == previous)
            {
                previous = i;
                continue;
            }

            previous = i;
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs `1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1`, removing duplicates only if they're adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a regular `Where` call.

```
int? previousPrice = null;

var output = myData.Where(d => {
  var result = !previousPrice.HasValue || previousPrice.Value != d.Price;
  previousPrice = d.Price;
  return result;
}).ToList();
```